Azure DevOps: access secret variable programmatically
Context: Monorepository (Nx) with multiple applications
In Azure DevOps I'm trying to retrieve the deployment token of my applications. Since it's not secure to store the token in a JSON on the repo, I want to save in a configuration file the name of the secret in secretName (that will be somewhere) and then retrieve it using a simple script:
    for app in $apps; do
       # Check if the deployment-config.json exists for the app
       configPath="apps/$app/deployment-configs/deployment-config.${{ parameters.target_environment }}.json"
       if [ -f "$configPath" ]; then
          secretName=$(jq -r '.secretName' "$configPath") # Retrieve secret name from config file
          # TODO: RETRIEVE SECRET STORED IN A SECURE PLACE!
       fi
    done

Now at this point I have the name of the variable containing my script.
Setting a pipeline secret doesn't work since I need to explicitly pass all the secrets as env parameters (not ideal when you have multiple apps over 3 different environments).
So something like secretValue=${!secretName} won't work.
Is there a way to achieve this without explicitly settings secrets as env? Using Azure KeyVault can be a valid way to implement
Update: get tokens with CLI
In my case, for static web apps, storing the tokens in a keyvault was not required since they could be directly accessed by calling az staticwebapp secrets list --name "$appName" --query "properties.apiKey" -o tsv

If you store the secrets on Azure DevOps (in a variable group or in a pipeline), it is not possible to use Azure DevOps REST API or CLI to get the values of secrets. To call the secrets in a script, you must use the 'env' key to map the secrets as environment variables for use.

For your case, you can consider storing the secrets on Azure Key Vault. In your Bash script, after fetching the name of secret, you can use the Azure CLI "az keyvault secret show" to fetch the value of secret based on the name. Also see "Retrieve a secret from Key Vault".
So, you can set you Bash script like as below:
for app in $apps; do
   # Check if the deployment-config.json exists for the app
   configPath="apps/$app/deployment-configs/deployment-config.${{ parameters.target_environment }}.json"
   if [ -f "$configPath" ]; then
      # Fetch the secret name from config file
      secretName=$(jq -r '.secretName' "$configPath")
      # Fetch the secret value using Azure CLI
      secretValue=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name "keyVaultName" --name "$secretName" --query value --output tsv)
   fi
done

In the pipeline of Azure DevOps, you can use the AzureCLI@2 task to run this Bash script like as below.
parameters:
# The name of the ARM service connection.
- name: ArmConnection
  type: string
  default: 'xxxx'

- name: target_environment
  type: string
  default: 'xxxx'
# the name of the Azure Key Vault.
- name: keyVaultName
  type: string
  default: 'xxxx'

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Retrieve secret'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      for app in $apps; do
         configPath="apps/$app/deployment-configs/deployment-config.${{ parameters.target_environment }}.json"
         if [ -f "$configPath" ]; then
            secretName=$(jq -r '.secretName' "$configPath")
            secretValue=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name "${{ parameters.keyVaultName }}" --name "$secretName" --query value --output tsv)
         fi
      done


The parameter 'ArmConnection' use to pass the name of an Azure Resource Manager service connection. It is used to connect to the Azure Subscription and Resource group where the Azure Key Vault is in. If you do not have existing ARM connection, you can go to "Project Settings"  > "Pipelines" > "Service connections" to create one.

The parameter 'keyVaultName' use to pass the name of the Azure Key Vault where the secrets are stored in.


In addition, after creating the ARM connection, ensure the App registration (or User Assigned Managed Identity) used by the connection has the Get and List permissions of secrets on the Azure Key Vault.

Find the App registration (or User Assigned Managed Identity) used by the ARM connection.


Assign the Get and List permissions of secrets to the App registration (or User Assigned Managed Identity) on the Azure Key Vault.





Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I will verify everything and then approve the answer

@AndreaCostanzo, You're welcome, and go ahead please.

Have you suggestions on how I should use that secret to deploy (is the token for a static web app, I realized just later I could retrieve it using az staticwebapp ...) programmatically from the script. I could only find the swa CLI but I'd like to use az CLI since I don't need to authenticate. I might create a separate question for that

It is a bit confusing to understand your requirements. If your actual concern in this post is about how to isolate the environment variables to be populated from different configuration JSON files during a pipeline run, please note that

System and user-defined variables also get injected as environment variables.

This includes the secrets your pipeline retrieves from Azure Key Vault via pipeline library or the AzureKeyVault@2 task, so that the secret values are accessible in subsequent steps.
You may consider referencing the variables in different job/stage scopes. Also, if that is the case, outputting variables in future job/stages may help.
If by any chance you would populate a secret value into a configuration JSON file, you may try with the 3rd-party marketplace extension task Replace Tokens.

No, I'm not keeping the secrets inside the JSON files, what I'm doing is keeping their names in a JSON file. The secrets needs to be stored in a safe place and be retrievable dynamically using the name. So what will be saved as environment variable is the name of the variable of the secret, not the secret itself

So you want to define environment variables with empty value? Those values are only available in the script session. You need to output those secrets to different jobs referencing different environments, as suggested in the answer?
